# Fill options for vector layers in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, circle

In leaflet, how can I manage the filling option? More specifically, I would like to fill inside a circle until a certain border not the whole geometry. Is that possible?  [image: graphical description]
I simply use L.Circle: [link](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle)

```
var annonciation_195 = L.circle([44.519, 6.760], 500,{color:'#C02900', weight:1, opacity:1, fillColor: '#D19D1F', fillOpacity:.5}).addTo(map);
```

I tried leaflet semicircle plugin [link](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet-semicircle), but it also does not have this option to my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add an inner circle after the first one with white `fillcolor` and eventually changing the `fillOpacity` value according to your needs:

```
var annonciation_195_outer = L.circle([44.519, 6.760], 500,{color:'#C02900', weight:1, opacity:1, fillColor: '#D19D1F', fillOpacity:.5}).addTo(map);
var annonciation_195_inner = L.circle([44.519, 6.760], 300,{color:'#C02900', weight:1, opacity:1, fillColor: '#FFFFFF', fillOpacity:.5}).addTo(map);
```

[image: donut]

Otherwise, if you want the inner circle void, use [Leaflet.Donut](https://github.com/americanpanorama/panorama/tree/master/src/Leaflet/Donut).

Comment: Thank you @afalciano but I want the inner circle to be void, not cover anything on map.

Comment: In this case you could try the Leaflet.Donut plugin.